# jprofiler jpcontroller can't connect to jvm when called with host:port

Tags: java, jvm, jprofiler

i want to profile my web application now this is what i do:
run jpenable.exe and after it finds thi jvm, it gives me a port so i can connect  to it using JProfiler GUI(for instance:12121)! now as I want to have commandline control i then try to connect jpcontroller using this command:

```
jpcontroller.exe localhost:12121
```

but it cannot connect and sticks there with no error! now if i use this command:

```
jpcontroller.exe <port>
```

then it works!
but actually i can't do this as i want to connect to a remote jvm!!

am i wrong some where?

Answer (score 0):

jpcontroller does not connect to the port that is opened by the profiling agent, but it uses JMX to connect to the process. For that to work on a remote computer, add the VM parameter

-Djprofiler.jmxServerPort=[port]

to the profiled process and use that port in jpcontroller. Then, an MBean server will be created that listens on that port.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot about that feature. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that's not working either! it says `No connection to an MBean server at 127.0.0.1:17187 could be made If the remote computer is only reachable via an IP address, please add
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[IP address] as a VM parameter to the remote VM` and i even done that and still not working!

Comment: Then the MBeanServer is not running. It may be that the MBeanServer cannot be initialized during attach. Try to add the -agentpath parameter as given by "Session->Integration wizards->New Remote Integration" as well as -Djprofiler.jmxServerPort=[port] to the start script of the profiled process, then you do not have to use jpenable.